# how to add forward slash to a word

Tags: regex, awk, scripting

Is there a way to add forward slash to a word ?
like this

test -> /test/

I have this file,

```
switch1  Ethernet13  1     4     5  
switch1  Ethernet14  1     4     5  
switch1  Ethernet15  1     4     5  
switch1  Ethernet8   1     4     5  
switch1  Ethernet16  1     4     5  
switch1  Ethernet1   2002  2697  2523  
switch1  Ethernet17  2002  2576  2515
```

and would like to change it like this,

```
/switch1/  /Ethernet13/  /1/     /4/     /5/  
/switch1/  /Ethernet14/  /1/     /4/     /5/  
/switch1/  /Ethernet15/  /1/     /4/     /5/  
/switch1/  /Ethernet8/   /1/     /4/     /5/  
/switch1/  /Ethernet16/  /1/     /4/     /5/  
/switch1/  /Ethernet1/   /2002/  /2697/  /2523/    
/switch1/  /Ethernet17/  /2002/  /2576/  /2515/
```

The reason I'm looking for this type of format is that I can use
it to find matching patterns with awk.
I tried this but it only printed 0 (zero) out,

```
awk '{print "\/$1\/}'
```

Thanks for any idea or suggestion.

Comment: Note that the unbalanced double quotes are a problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the following `sed` command:

```
sed 's~\([^ \t]\+\)~/\1/~g' file.txt
```

It surrounds all groups of non-space characters `([^ \t]\+)` with slashes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following.

```
sed -r 's!(\S+)!/\1/!g' file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

If your awk has the `gensub()` function ...

```
awk '{ print gensub(/(\w+)/, "/\\1/", "g") }' file.txt
```

---

About `gensub`

- http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html

> `gensub(regexp, replacement, how [, target]) #`
>
> > **`gensub()`** is a general substitution function ... [has] more features than the standard `sub()` and `gsub()` functions ... [has] ability to *specify components of a regexp* in the replacement text

Comment: It was a nice find when I found out about `gensub` when trying to help someone else trouble-shoot... and then a big let down when I found out they didn't have `gawk`... Appreciate the link and the mention that `gensub` may not be there.

Answer (score 1):

Using brute force and ignorance, you could use:

```
awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) $i = "/"$i"/"; print }'
```

This replaces each field with the value surrounded by slashes. The only thing to be aware of is that it messes up the spacing between the fields, but if you're going to use the output for searching, that won't be a problem.

If you want each field on a separate line (which is perhaps more useful for the proposed purpose), then:

```
awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) print "/"$i"/"; }'
```

Comment: To preserve the spaces you could do `awk '{gsub(/[^ ]+/,"\/&\/")}1' file`

Comment: This is to say thanks to all the answers. I'm new here. Even though, the help page says I shouldn't say thanks, but it feels weird not too.